# boxplot not in one vertical position python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to make a boxplot with two columns. The total length of the columns is 50. I want to plot each 10 values of one column and than the other than on the right side and again the last 10 also on the right side of the one before and so on. Besides I would like to plot in the same figure the second columns boxplot pairwise. So the first 10 of both should be close to each other and the other 10 rows should be close to each other. Right now I am plotting only one column, but all in the same axis/position. How do I need to index my data that the plots are sorted horizontally.

Besides I would like to see all the median values of the plots. 
Currently for one column: 
[image]

What I actually want to do looks like: 
[image]

```
  df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,50).T)
  fig = plt.subplots()
  plt.boxplot(df.iloc[0:10,0])
  plt.boxplot(df.iloc[10:20,0])
  plt.boxplot(df.iloc[20:30,0])
  plt.boxplot(df.iloc[:40,0])
  plt.boxplot(df.iloc[:40,0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the third http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html example, with random data as per your question. You can change the names of the set with a string if you want to. The key is to write down the different characteristics in different columns of your dataframe, so that you get a 100 rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100), columns=['y'])

set_array = np.zeros(50)
for x in range(5):
    set_array[x*10:(x+1)*10] = x*10
set_array = np.concatenate((set_array, set_array))

group_array = np.empty(100, dtype='str')
for x in range(100):
    if x<50:
        group_array[x]='A'
    else:
        group_array[x]='B'

df['set'] = pd.Series(set_array)
df['hue'] = pd.Series(group_array)

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = sns.boxplot(x="set", y="y", hue="hue",
              data=df)
```

Comment: in your example are A and B stacked vertically, how do I handle this if the A and B are in two different columns ?

Comment: You can concatenate the two columns using `pd.concat((df[0],df[1]))` so that it becomes stacked.